# Chocolatey not working

Tags: chocolatey

When I try to run chocolatey from the Command Prompt, it gives me this error:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Chocolatey\bin\chocolatey.exe.
```

I've tried changing the environmental variable, but then it gives me (almost) the same thing:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin\chocolatey.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide more information here. This is not enough information to make a reasonable determination of your situation.

UPDATE: Try reinstalling. If that doesn't work, try a `where.exe choco` to try to determine where it is looking for the executable and if there is any conflicts. The last thing one could do is back up the lib/bin folders (minus choco.exe executables in the bin directory) and blowing the rest away and reinstalling. Plus maybe a restart.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1 x64, and it has worked for me before, but only recently has it stopped working. When I go to the directory where it's stored and type dir, chocolatey.exe is there, and there are also the other files for chocolatey. What other information do you need?

Comment: So if you go to `c:\Chocolatey\bin` in your shell and type `.\choco.exe`, what do you get?

Comment: The system cannot find the file C:\Chocolatey\bin\choco.exe. Also, choco.exe then gets deleted.

Comment: Let's chalk it up to a bad install - just install it again over the top of itself.

Comment: I've done that many, many times, and it still doesn't work. In fact, I had to reinstall it to try running .\choco.exe

Comment: I'm really not sure what is different about your situation, but perhaps you can elaborate more up in the question about your environment.

Comment: Try `where.exe choco`  or in powershell `&where.exe choco` and see what the output is

Comment: Clearly there is something going on.

Comment: I reinstalled choco, and now it works fine, for some reason. When I ran where.exe choco, it gave me C:\Chocolatey\bin\choco.exe, though.

Answer (score 0):

The chocolatey executable should be `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe`

Try the install steps again: https://chocolatey.org/install